# Destructuring map argument with :keys vs old fashioned let

Tags: clojure

Learning Clojure from a Scheme background, my immediate instinct was to write code as follows:

```
(defn my-func [data]
  (let [right (:right data)
        left  (:left data)]
     ... body ... ))
```

However, I was told very soon that pattern matching is one the great features of Clojure (or indeed Haskell and Scala), so I felt compelled to write:

```
(defn my-func [ {:keys [right left] } ]
   ... body ...)
```

So my code is now littered with this type of syntax. Somehow I don't like it. I find my code less appealing to look at, maybe even less readable (but this is probably due to lack of experience of idiomatic Clojure, so it will get better with time).

So I wanted to ask, is there a fundamental reason to use one style over the other? For example, is the compiler generating byte-codes which is far more efficient in the second case. Or is there other reasons I should be aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Destructuring is not pattern matching!](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/237026) When you write this:

```
(defn my-func [{:keys [right left]}]
  ,,,)
```

It's the same as this:

```
(defn my-func [data]
  (let [{:keys [right left]} data]
    ,,,))
```

Which is the same as this:

```
(defn my-func [data]
  (let [right (:right data)
        left (:left data)]
    ,,,))
```

[As Piotrek pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37888021/5044950), there are no performance benefits to using the more concise form. However, there is still a benefit: namely, concision.

[As Alan pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37887826/destructuring-map-argument-with-keys-vs-old-fashioned-let#comment63231073_37888021), the main advantage of `:keys` destructuring is that you only have to write each key name once instead of twice.

[As you pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37887826/5044950), doing destructuring directly in the argument vector of a function can make your code less readable, which is why it's actually not very common in Clojure.

The great thing is that, since destructuring is not complected with parameter naming in Clojure, you can get the best of both worlds (the second form I gave above):

```
(defn my-func [data]
  (let [{:keys [right left]} data]
    ,,,))
```

This way, you get both readability (especially if you name your parameter something better than `data`) and concision (by using `:keys` destructuring).

Comment: Thank you very much Sam! Thanks also for the reference on destructuring v pattern matching

Answer (score 3):

The `:keys` destructuring is just a syntax sugar and is actually expanded into a series of calls to `get` and assignments to symbols. For example:

```
(macroexpand-1
  '(let [{:keys [a b]} {:a 1 :b 2}]))
```

gets expanded into:

```
(let*
 [map__2507
  {:a 1, :b 2}
  map__2507
  (if (clojure.core/seq? map__2507) (clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap/create (clojure.core/seq map__2507)) map__2507)
  a
  (clojure.core/get map__2507 :a)
  b
  (clojure.core/get map__2507 :b)])
```

The main goal of destructuring (notice that it is only destructuring - not full pattern matching) is terse code and there is no performance optimisation involved.

To illustrate how the code without `:keys` destructuring is more verbose take a look at the example:

```
(let [{:keys [id name address age salary]} person]
  ...)
```

vs

```
(let [id (:id person)
      name (:name person)
      address (:address person)
      age (:age person)
      salary (:salary person)]
  ...)
```

Comment: As Piotrek mentioned, the big benefit is that you don't need to repeat each  name twice (e.g. symbol "right" and keyword ":right"), and the symbol "data" is removed from each line as well as the arg list.

Comment: Thanks v much Piotrek/Alan

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, this is from the Clojure [Library Coding Standards](http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Library+Coding+Standards):

> Idiomatic code uses destructuring a lot. However, you should only destructure in the arg list if you want to communicate the substructure as part of the caller contract. Otherwise, destructure in a first-line let. Example: [my snake code](https://github.com/stuarthalloway/programming-clojure/commit/7758eac3b0434654902835fde47c854708538864) from the book fails this test, doing too much destructuring in arg lists.

Comment: Thank you very much Valentin !